# R not working Mac OS Catalina: dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libicuuc.54.dylib

Tags: r, macos

For some reason, I can no longer load R through the command line. However, R continues to work through R studio.

Whenever I type `R` into terminal, the below message appears:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libicuuc.54.dylib 
Referenced from: /Users/claflamm/miniconda3/lib/R/lib/libR.dylib
Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

I am currently running MacOS Catalina (10.15.5 (19F101)). I have tried troubleshooting through other StackOverflow forums from users who documented similar issues, but nothing so far has worked.

This includes:

Updating conda `conda update -c rdonnellyr -c main --all`

Updating conda `conda update conda` and then installing R essentials `conda install r-essentials`

Installing R outside of conda `homebrew install R`

And I had also tried copying a lib document over to another folder as suggested, but I unfortunately did not keep record of this.

If anyone has any other suggestions, I would greatly appreciate some help with this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

--Solved--

Did not realize I was automatically initializing a base conda environment.

As soon as I deactivated the environment with:

```
conda deactivate
```

I was able to successfully call R from the terminal.